# make bot play youtube videos in voicechat discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my bot being able to join voicechats, leave them and also be able to play youtube videos via links on command. this is the code I got so far. Joining and leaving is no problem. trying to get the link from the "play" command is kind of difficult for me

```py
class Voice(commands.Cog):
    def init(self, bot):
      self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("VoiceCog loaded")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.casefold().startswith("join voice rachel"):
            channel = message.author.voice.channel
            server = message.guild
            await channel.connect() #join voicechat cmd

        elif message.content.casefold().startswith("leave voice rachel"):
            channel = message.guild.voice_client
            await channel.disconnect() #leave voicechat cmd

        elif message.content.casefold().startswith("rachel play"):
            channel = message.author.voice.channel
            player = await channel.create_ytdl_player(url)
            player.start() #this would be the play youtube-link cmd
        else:
            return
```

I always use `on_message`, because it does more suit my purpose of the bot. I also tried it with `ctx`, but that didn't end well :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the message to extract the url. So you can split the string using the space. For example you could do something similar to:

```
parts = message.content.split()
url = parts[-1] #Assuming the last item in the message is the url
```

Btw, your `on_message` event should have the decorator `@commands.Cog.listener()` not a `commands.command()` decorator.

Comment: about the decorator.. yeah I copied that wrong. originally I had this one implemented.
I tried it as you told me and now I get the error `"VoiceChannel" object has no attribute "create_ytdl_player"`